# How to run migration (DBMigrator) on IIS?

Tags: asp.net-core, abp.io, dbmigrator

I using Abp.io Framework.

how to run DBMigrator solution on Share Hosting?
I can only access DB using phpmyadmin.
i cannot connect to db using connection string.

i try deploy DbMigrator solution like HttpApi.Host, but getting error
**"HTTP Error 500.33 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core request handler"**

is that possible i can run migration on this server?

i try deploy DbMigrator solution like HttpApi.Host, but getting error
**"HTTP Error 500.33 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core request handler"**

is that possible i can run migration on this server?

or i need request Server Admin run using command ?